# Getting additional character while Converting to UTF-8 Python

Tags: python, utf-8

I am trying to convert the html encode character as part of the input string to UTF8 in Python. I am getting additional character as Ã. How to get rid of it in python.

Example:
I supposed to get the output as as "SlimRun®".
But, I am getting SlimRunÂ®

I am using unescape methond from HTMLParser()

Answer (score 0):

UTF8 is a multibyte encoding so you can encode more than 1 million characters. You have to decode the utf8-encoded string:

```
b'SlimRun\xc2\xae'.decode('utf8')
```

Comment: Here is my code. import sys
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser
h=HTMLParser() input="SlimRun&#174;"
output=h.unescape(input)

Comment: With your code I get the unicode string `u'SlimRun\xae'`.

Comment: I was able to get rid of Ã using raw-unicode-escape. But now, when the string has html encoding character as &#xFFFD; it transform as \ufffd. It should transform as � . Any idea?